# Is the surface of a closed object which encloses a point charge always equipotential?

Tags: electrostatics

[image]

If I consider A and B to be two points and charge q is placed inside the cavity ( kindly ignore charge Q) . Is the surface always equipotential  regardless of the shape of the body ?  Is this possible  when the charge q is not even at the geometrical centre? Can some please clarify my doubts?

Answer (score 2):

> Is the surface of a closed object which encloses a point charge always equipotential?

Yes, with a few caveats.

- The body is a conductor
- There are no time-varying magnetic fields
- You are in equilibrium, (which is established in a concuctor in a very, very short time, for example $10^{-16}$ seconds)